# Laravel withError function not working

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

I was testing this new framework (Laravel) and upto now i'm following those examples which they have put in their documentation. All is going good till i got this problem.

i am calling `Redirect::to('\signup')->withErrors($validator->messages());` but its not showing anything 
but if i just print it like `print_r($validator->messages());` it shows me the errors. Please help me and tell me where i am going wrong?

**Controller**

```
public function registerUser(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
            'username' => 'required|email|unique:user',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
            'fullname' => 'required'
        )
    );
    if($validator->fails()){

        return Redirect::to('signup')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }else{
        return Redirect::route('user');
    }

}
```

**Route**
`Route::get('/signup',array('as'=>'signup', 'uses'=>'HomeController@signUp'));`

**View**

```
<?php print_r($errors) ; ?>
```

Comment: Could you paste the code how you display the errorS?

Comment: You say in the question that you call ``withErrors($validator->messages())``, but in the code sample you're calling ``withErrors($validator)`` - which is it?

Comment: i have tried both withErrors($validator) and withErrors($validator->messages()), neither of them work.. @nhbjgfcxhgchg

Comment: @RobinValk im just using print_r($errors) on the view page

Comment: well, HOW are you showing the errors in your views?

Comment: Like Damien and Robin said: you do realise you actually need to do something with the errors, right? They don't show up magically unless you put some code in your view, too. :)

Comment: @nhbjgfcxhgchg please review the comments, i said that im using print_r($errors) in the view. Also i have edited the question now

Comment: We got that a print_r shows the errors, but that's not your problem, right? You said you cannot display them normally, so you're likely doing it wrong on that part...

Comment: @DamienPirsy sir my problem is i can print those error in the controller by simply print_r($validator->messages()) but when i pass it to Route::to('signup')->withError($validator->messages()), it doesnt show my in view ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I changed the `secure` option to true in `session` file (in `config` folder) and was testing it on local server without `https`. That is why my errors were not showing in view.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the relevant information from the Laravel website:

```
Route::post('register', function()
{
    $rules = array(...);

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
    }
});
```

Which you can reference from Blade like this...

```
<?php echo $errors->first('email'); ?>
```

Notice how $errors is an object? You call `print_r($errors)` which may not produce very useful output.

Try this...

```
<?php
    var_dump($errors->first('username'));
    var_dump($errors->first('password'));
    var_dump($errors->first('email'));
?>
```

**Also:** Your [unique](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique):user validation should probably be `unique:user,username`. Use the database table name and column name, not the model values.

**Note:** If you are testing this in a browser, you may want to look into using [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork), which allows you to see Session information from the browser without the print_r/var_dump calls.

Comment: sir thanks for your reply but i found my problem.. i changed secure = true in session file (in config folder) and was testing it on local webserver without https, so that is why i wasnt getting the reply as error messages were stored in Sessions. But still thanks for your detail answer and some other things that you pointed out, really appreciated :)

Comment: [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) is also pretty usefull :D