# Laravel redirect back or route with message not working

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble to make `redirect()->route()->with()` or `redirect()->back()->with()`. It is redirecting but without flash message.

I can create separate flash messages then redirect but I want to know if there is any issue in my code or this is the way it works?

### Not working

public function destroy(User $user)
{
    $userId = $user->id;

```
if ($user->id == 1 || $user->is('super') || $user->isRoot($user)) {

    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Cannot delete the user. The user may be a super or root user.');

} else {

    if (User::destroy($user->id)) {

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index')->with('success', 'User deleted successfully.');

    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Cannot delete the user.');
    }

}
```

### Working Code

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{
    $userId = $user->id;

    if ($user->id == 1 || $user->is('super') || $user->isRoot($user)) {

        Session::flash('error', 'Cannot delete the user. The user may be a super or root user.');

        return redirect()->back();

    } else {

        if (User::destroy($user->id)) {

            Session::flash('success', 'User #' . $userId . ' is deleted successfully.');

            return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');

        } else {
            Session::flash('error', 'Cannot delete the user.');

            return redirect()->back();
        }

    }
}
```

> I have also tried using `withError` and `withSuccess` but none of them
>   are working.

Comment: Try to print the session variable. And see what you have got

Answer (score 2):

Your first code seems correct, this must be a problem in your blade file. Try something like this

`@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('error') }}
    </div>
@endif`

Answer (score 1):

It tried using this code and got the results. I think there's a problem with your blade code.

**Controller**

```
public function destroy(User $user) { 
$userId = $user->id;

if ($user->id == 1 || $user->is('super') || $user->isRoot($user)) {

    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Cannot delete the user. The user may be a super or root user.');

} else {

    if (User::destroy($user->id)) {

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index')->with('success', 'User deleted successfully.');

    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Cannot delete the user.');
    }

}
```

**Blade**

```
           @if (Session::has('error'))

            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">{{ Session::get('error') }} 
            </div>

            @endif
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: This is what exactly I am doing still not getting it working,

Answer (score 0):

`with('error')` this is store in session. if **web middleware** is not applied on your route then you'll not get the error.

Check `php artisan route:list` to make sure the **web middleware** is present on all your routes and that it's only applied once.

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910790/9978078) it might be helpful to you.